# Intellij : spark filter on a dataset is marked as error if no named variable is provided

Tags: scala, apache-spark

This line used to work perfectly :

```
    val jobContent = tupleJobContent.filter(_._1 != null).map(_._1)
```

`tupleJobContent` is of type `Dataset[Tuple1[Job]]`.

Today I open Intellij, and it's flagged as "cannot resolve reference filter with such signature".

On the other hand this one is not flagged

```
    val jobContent = tupleJobContent.filter(tuple => tuple._1 != null).map(_._1)
```

The error only happens in Intellij, `gradle build` does not return any error, but takes now 2 minutes instead of 30 seconds.

That's why I was thinking some change in my environment, but I can't think of any.

Comment: Whenever I see issues like yours where IDEA shows an issue while sbt or gradle do not is to simply live with it and hope one day IDEA understands Scala and Spark better. Also, I'd rather not use `Dataset.filter` since it loads all the big data onto a JVM which may be too much. Use untyped `DataFrame.where` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the tip with DataFrame, I'll test it today !